# How to get piv card authentication and certificate information

Tags: .net, authentication, pki

I searched around there is a IIS related method (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732116.aspx) but I can't get it to work.

I need to get the piv card authenticated from a web application then return certificate to the web application. How can I do that in C#.net

UPDATE: just in case, someone else is interested. I found a solution (not perfect) but working which I put in this thread [Smart card authentication using a client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760613/smart-card-authentication-using-a-client-certificate/11853354#11853354)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (not perfect but working) which I put in this thread [Smart card authentication using a client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760613/smart-card-authentication-using-a-client-certificate/11853354#11853354)