# Smart card authentication using a client certificate

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, client-certificates

I have a third party web application and now my manager wants to add smart card authentication to some of the pages (not the whole application) and return certificate information. What I'm thinking is to add buttons to those pages, and in the `onclick` event, I will do the client certificate authentication (where a certificate selection window will appear followed by the "PIN" window) and return certificate object for further processing.

I initially thought about a web service to do the client certificate authentication and return certificate information, which would be great because we might consider using that web service in other web applications (on different platforms). However, I couldn't find any code example that did this. Then I found the [IIS solution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770480%28v=ws.10%29).

I have now created a separate folder with a page that requires a client certificate. On the button click event, I redirect to that page. Then on that page, I retrieve the certificate information using the `X509Certificate` class. I don't think this helps me in what I'm trying to do, or at least I don't know how it helps.

So my question is (sorry for the long background description)

1. How can I redirect back from that page with the certification result?
2. If possible, any reference on how to build up a web service that does the client certificate authentication in the same way that IIS does?

Thanks

**Update**
I looked around and still don't have a clue on how to achieve this. I'm not sure how to code at SSL/TLS handshake stage for the web service. I don't know how to return the certification back to the page I invoke this function either. So what I'm trying to do now is to redirect from a protected page that requires client authentication. It seems the web server caches the authentication result. Here is my third question, I hope someone can answer.

How can I clean out the authentication result at the end of the page session so that each time the page is visited, it request client authentication (where a certificate selection window will appear followed by the "PIN" window)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your app is hosted in IIS then simply add (in web.config) a section that says client certificate is required for those pages. THe browser will then ask the user for a cert.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked the SSL Settings to required on that folder in IIS. Is that not enough?

Comment: it should be - assuming that the client system( browser etc) is set up to use smart card certs

Comment: Here is what happened. I have a page that is NOT under restricted folder, page1. In script of page1, I use redirect to the page (page2) that requested a client certificate under a folder having SSL setting to required in IIS. When I visit page1 for the first time, it prompts the certificate selection window then the PIN window then display page2. Then I close the window, open a new one, type in page1's address, this time the certificate selection window shows, after I select the same certificate, it does not challenge me with PIN window, just display page2. I want the PIN window always trigger

Comment: this is normal smart card behavior. once a user enters PIN to unlock the smart card they dont need to do it again. You could probably force it if you wrote code to run on the user's machine; (real code, not javascript). A browser plugin probably could do it but I am not sure. You need to call the smart card functions directly (on the user machine)

Comment: Hi @pm100, How can I force the pin in the code ?  This smart card behavior of asking the pin everytime I authenticate is killing the usage.

Comment: u need to authenticate at login and then go to a different part of the website that uses session cookie not client cert . Ie only have require cert on one specific part of the web site

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a caching feature which, by default, allows applications to access the private key for a limited time after the initial PIN prompt, or until the application is closed completely.

To disable, set this registry key. (Or use a GPO)

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography]
"PrivKeyCacheMaxItems"=dword:00000000
"PrivKeyCachePurgeIntervalSeconds"=dword:00000000
```