# How to restrict specific pages to Certificate Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, iis-7, x509certificate

In my ASP.NET web-application I have created Default.aspx (set as my start page), and a new folder called SmartCard with WebForm1.aspx inside of it. How do I configure Web.Config to prompt user for Certificate upon visiting SmartCard/WebForm1.aspx but NOT when Default.aspx loads?

In the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760613/smart-card-authentication-using-a-client-certificate) question:

> if your app is hosted in IIS then simply add (in web.config) a section that says client certificate is required for those pages. THe browser will then ask the user for a cert.

From the above answer, I looked some more on StackOverflow and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719416/can-client-certificate-settings-be-configured-in-the-web-config). From their accepted answer I put the following section in Web.Config:

```
<location path="SmartCard">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <access sslFlags="SslRequireCert" />
    </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

I then modified applicationHost.config in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config (or appropriate directory for your install) and change the following line:

```
<section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

to:

```
<section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

However, I still get prompted for a Certificate on site load. I first get the following screen:

[image]

After clicking "Continue to this website" I then get prompted to selected a Certificate when Default.aspx loads. However, I only want to get prompted to selected a Certificate when SmartCard/WebForm1.aspx loads!

ANY help is greatly appreciated!

---

Here are my site settings in IIS-7:

**SSL settings:**

[image]

**Site Bindings:**
[image]
[image]

*MyDevCert is self-signed

---

### Update:

I created a new Web.Config file inside of SmartCard directory with the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>

    <security>
       <access sslFlags="SslRequireCert" />
    </security>
    <system.web></system.web>

 </configuration>
```

I then removed the 'location' tag from base Web.Config.

Base Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

However, I still get "There is a problem with this website's security certificate" screen and I get prompted for certificate once I click "Continue to this website"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm seeing, you can only have a single value for `sslFlags`.

See http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/access
And https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689458(v=VS.90).aspx

> The sslFlags attribute can be one of the following possible values. The default is None.

Comment: Even if I changed the value of sslFlags to only: SslRequireCert. I still get prompted for a certificate on site load.

Comment: @lucidgold Try removing the `<location>` section out of your base web.config entirely. Create a separate web.config in the "SmartCard" directory. Put the extracted config section into the new web.config. I'm curious if .Net/IIS is not assuming SSL sitewide since you change `sslFlags` from `None` in the root web.config regardless of your location configuration.

Comment: I have updated my question and made the changed you suggested. However, I still get same reaction. Is my new Web.config correct?

Comment: @lucidgold I'm assuming your "MyDevCert" is self signed. Is that incorrect? If it is self signed, you're always going to get that warning. That is expected behavior. Do you still get the error on your Default.aspx page?

Comment: That is correct, it is self-signed. However, I still get prompted for Certificate when Default.aspx loads. I only want to be asked when I goto SmartCard/WebForm1.aspx

Comment: @lucidgold Not to be a pain but your new web.config doesn't look well-formed while your base config does. You should remove the `system.webServer` node and close out the `configuration` node. I don't think this will fix your issue so I'm still knocking it around in my head.

Comment: Updated SmartCard directory Web.Config. But it doesnt like my changes, I get an error: "The configuration section 'security' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration"

Comment: @lucidgold D'oh! Sorry. I got `system.webServer` mixed up with `system.web`. I meant to remove the system.web node. You'll absolutely need the `system.webServer` node.